# Updating tables in VBA ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

i need help solving my problem with vba update statement:

In my form i have a click form that when i click it execute this procedure :

```
Dim strSQL As String
 Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

  strSQL = "UPDATE dbo.Firma_test SET Fax = " & Me![subforma_companie].Form!fax & _
          "[E-mail] = " & Me![subforma_companie].Form!email & _
          "WHERE Company_Code = " & Me![subforma_companie].Form!Cod
```

When i execute i tell me that he didn't see the email field, what can i do???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a space before the `WHERE` clause:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE dbo.Firma_test SET Fax = " & Me![subforma_companie].Form!fax & _
      ", [E-mail] = '" & Me![subforma_companie].Form!email & _
      "' WHERE Company_Code = " & Me![subforma_companie].Form!Cod
```

Also you may want to consider some form of prevention of `SQL Injection` just incase a user enters `DROP TABLE db.Firma_test` in the `subforma_companie form`

Comment: Also you probably want to quote the strings, like Email.

Comment: i get INCORRECT syntax near E-mail

Comment: @Sergio - check my edit you'll need the additional `,` before E-mail

Comment: And like ta.speot.is states, add quotes the e-mail

Comment: @Sergio - good stuff.  Please mark it as the answer :-)